# How to set to database current date time in this form?

Tags: php, database, datetime, insert

The code is working good but i can't find any code to set date&time PLZ HELP
Here is my code does it work in any way?

```
 mysql_query("INSERT comments SET name='$name', fb='$fb', msg_id_fk='1', date_time='$date', comments='$comments'")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `date_time=now()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`
try this code
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");

`

Comment: THNX YOU i have used that with a combination <3